# Using two fields in findorcreate.map.isExactMatch in Live Agent

Tags: liveagent

I am using salesforce for a Live chat to case form.

There are two fields i would like the user to enter info.

1. Member ID
2. Email ID

Now i am using this

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value="Email,true;" />
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value="Email,true;" />
```

It is working fine. But my requirement is
1. If the user enters the Member ID then it should search only on Member ID. 
2. If the user does not enter Member ID then only it should search on Email ID.

How to do this ?
I tried creating similar set of code using isExactMatch for both fiels. But it is creating a new record. Is it possible in salesforce ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most elegant approach but I would use JavaScript to modify the values of the input fields before submission.

Evaluate if the field has a value if it doesn't then change the value of the "Live Agent Input field" or remove it.

Comment: Pepe Floyd thanks for the reply. Here i have one more concern, say the user enters the proper Member ID but a wrong typo in email field. Now if i use email match, SF will create a new record which is very wrong. Here the basic problem is all customers may not have Member ID's (especially the new prospects who have come just for an enquiry). Any suggestion how to handle this situation

Comment: A possible solution could be to use JS remoting to search for the email the customer entered before the form is submitted, you could implement your own matching logic there and return a value to the field.