# Problem with in Live chat map.doFind

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat

In live agent i am using  the below code to search the member based on email id and attach case to the member.

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value="Email,true;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value="Email,true;" />
```

If i use the below code to find match with multiple fields then even if one field is true then it will attach the case to that member. Here assume that

```
<input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.doFind:Contact" value="Email,true;MemberNumber__c,true;FirstName,true;LastName,true;" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="liveagent.prechat.findorcreate.map.isExactMatch:Contact" value="Email,true;MemberNumber__c,true;FirstName,true;LastName,true;" />
```

1. Only First name entered by member matches with the system record
2. All other fields are different. It will still based on one true condition it will go and attach the case to that member.
3. How to use percentage match here like if First name, last name, Member name matches(atleast 3 fields) then go ahead and attach case to member, otherwise just create the case don't attach to any member.

I got an idea from this article [Using two fields in findorcreate.map.isExactMatch in Live Agent](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45132/using-two-fields-in-findorcreate-map-isexactmatch-in-live-agent)

But just wanted to know did anybody approach this type to scenario using prechat api.

Comment: I did it with just matching email, do you need multiple matches?

Comment: yes.. i want multiple with OR condition